# Ошибка в коде при использовании Map.Entry<String,nout>e: nTreeMap.entrySet()

Tags: java

При реализации данного кода (см. ниже) на экран выводиться пустая таблица:

Вывод в текстовый файл успешно осуществлен!

```
_________________________________________________________________________
 Идентификатор | Произв-ть процессора |Такт частота     |  (Объем Озу)! 
_______________|______________________|_________________|________________
_______________|______________________|_________________|________________
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно заменить в коде.
Код программы:

```
public class TreeMapOfNout implements IMethodsForCollections{

    private TreeMap<String,nout> nTreeMap;
    private Scanner scan;

    public TreeMapOfNout()//konstructor
    {
         nTreeMap = new TreeMap<String,nout>();
    }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void printAllCollection() {
        System.out.printf("________________________________________________________________________\r\n");
        System.out.printf(" Идентификатор | Произв-ть процессора |Такт частота     |  (Объем Озу)! \r\n");
        System.out.printf("_______________|______________________|_________________|________________\r\n");
        for( Map.Entry <String,nout> e: nTreeMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(" "+e.getValue().getId()+""+e.getValue().getNameCompany()+""+e.getValue().getSiquence()+""+e.getValue().getRam());
        }
        System.out.println("_______________|______________|_________________|________________");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void loadCollectionFromFile(String pathOfFile) {
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(pathOfFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Файла не найден666!");
            System.exit(0);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(in.hasNext()){
            nout noutTemp = new nout(0, "", 0, 0);
            noutTemp.setId(in.nextInt());
            noutTemp.setRam(in.nextInt());
            noutTemp.setSiquence(in.nextInt());
            noutTemp.setNameCompany(in.next());
            nTreeMap.put(noutTemp.getNameCompany(), noutTemp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так вы заполняете где-то nTreeMap  данными?

Comment: данные считываются из файла

Comment: @Alexandr Пожалуйста, внесите все дополнения в ваш вопрос. Для этого, воспользуйтесь кнопкой [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Нашлась причина ошибки : порядок следования данных в файле не совпадал с порядком их считывания в методе.
Произвёл замену с

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
            Nout noutTemp = new Nout(0, "", 0, 0);
            String[] strings = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            noutTemp.setId(Integer.parseInt(strings[0]));
        }
```

на

```
 while (in.hasNext()) {
                nout noutTemp = new nout(0, "", 0, 0);
                noutTemp.setId(in.nextInt()) 
}
```

и с `private TreeMap(String, nout)`

на  `private TreeMap(Integer, nout)`

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день Alexandr. Вот рабочий вариант вашей программы. Сделано поверхностно, но работает, выравнивание элементов в таблице отсутствует(при желании думаю вам не составит труда его сделать). Вариант с разбиением строки, как в моём случае тоже можно заменить.

```
 class Nout {
    private Integer id;
    private String nameCompany;
    private Integer siquence;
    private Integer ram;

    Nout(Integer id, String nameCompany, Integer siquence, Integer ram) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nameCompany = nameCompany;
        this.siquence = siquence;
        this.ram = ram;
    }

    public String getNameCompany() {
        return nameCompany;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getSiquence() {
        return siquence;
    }

    public Integer getRam() {
        return ram;
    }

    public void setNameCompany(String nameCompany) {
        this.nameCompany = nameCompany;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSiquence(Integer siquence) {
        this.siquence = siquence;
    }

    public void setRam(Integer ram) {
        this.ram = ram;
    }
}

public class TreeMapOfNout {
    private TreeMap<String, Nout> nTreeMap;

    public TreeMapOfNout()//konstructor
    {
        nTreeMap = new TreeMap<String, Nout>();
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void printAllCollection() {
        System.out.printf("________________________________________________________________________\r\n");
        System.out.printf(" Идентификатор | Произв-ль процессора |Такт частота     |  (Объем Озу)! \r\n");
        System.out.printf("_______________|______________________|_________________|________________\r\n");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Nout> e : nTreeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(" " + e.getValue().getId() + "                   " + e.getValue().getNameCompany() + "               "
                    + e.getValue().getSiquence() + "                    " + e.getValue().getRam());
        }
        System.out.println("_______________|______________________|_________________|________________");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void loadCollectionFromFile(String pathOfFile) {
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(pathOfFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Файла не найден666!");
            System.exit(0);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            Nout noutTemp = new Nout(0, "", 0, 0);
            String[] strings = in.nextLine().split(" ");

            noutTemp.setId(Integer.parseInt(strings[0]));
            noutTemp.setRam(Integer.parseInt(strings[1]));
            noutTemp.setSiquence(Integer.parseInt(strings[2]));
            noutTemp.setNameCompany(strings[3]);
            nTreeMap.put(noutTemp.getNameCompany(), noutTemp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMapOfNout base = new TreeMapOfNout();
        base.loadCollectionFromFile("F:\\baseComp.txt");
        base.printAllCollection();
    }
}
```

Считает данные из текстового файла следующего вида: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Многое зависит тут от того откуда вы считываете данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Alexandr откуда данные берёте, в данном примере информация о компьютерах храниться в текстовом файле. У вас где она храниться?